# Is it usually trustworthy to play online with a used copy of a game?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I saw Bad Company 2 used at a game store, and I was thinking of picking it up.

In general, are there be any issues to be aware of for playing online if the copy is used, which would discourage one from buying a used copy with the intent to play online? One concern I have is that the previous owner may still have the CD-key, and be able to play online without the install disks, which could interfere with my playing online. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You must check if the used game required the permanent association of the cd-key with an online account.

Because, if the previous owner of the game has registered the cd-key online with username and password, you'll not be able to register the game anymore.

Play online with an used game is not a problem, if the cd-key is still valid.

Comment: Assuming that that person isn't trying to also play online at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Merluz is right that a permanent account association (or even an un-doable one that hasn't been undone) could screw things upn  In some cases, though, you can contact the company/service with proof that you have the original media and they will give you access or give you a new key.

You're also right that many games, for example Halo: CE for PC, don't allow games using the same serial to go online at the same time. That's something of a minor issue unless your key uas been widely distributed, though.  A greater problem is that your key might be banned entirely, whether due to the actions of the previous owner or due to a detected attempt to re-use the CD key.  Again, contacting the banning party with proof of your ownership might help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique key, which is only associated with one account.

However I'm currently playing my old copy on a friends box/account, and have had no issues in playing the game online. Go for it. Nice game.

(I'm psyching myself up for BF3)